# Swift callback functions

Tags: swift, macos, the-amazing-audio-engine

I'm trying to use [The Amazing Audio Engine](http://theamazingaudioengine.com/) to record some audio using Swift on OS X. To do this, I need to implement a callback function that will receive the audio and do something with it. The documentation has some [examples](http://theamazingaudioengine.com/doc/_receiving-_audio.html) on how to do this with Objective-C:

```
@interface MyAudioReceiver : NSObject <AEAudioReceiver>
@end
@implementation MyAudioReceiver
static void receiverCallback(__unsafe_unretained MyAudioReceiver *THIS,
 __unsafe_unretained AEAudioController *audioController,
 void *source,
 const AudioTimeStamp *time,
 UInt32 frames,
 AudioBufferList *audio) {

 // Do something with 'audio'
}
-(AEAudioReceiverCallback)receiverCallback {
 return receiverCallback;
}
@end
...
id<AEAudioReceiver> receiver = [[MyAudioReceiver alloc] init];
```

or

```
id<AEAudioReceiver> receiver = [AEBlockAudioReceiver audioReceiverWithBlock:
 ^(void *source,
 const AudioTimeStamp *time,
 UInt32 frames,
 AudioBufferList *audio) {
 // Do something with 'audio'
}];
```

This is as far as I got:

```
var audioController: AEAudioController? = nil
audioController = AEAudioController(audioDescription: AEAudioStreamBasicDescriptionInterleaved16BitStereo, inputEnabled: true)
do {
    try audioController?.start()
} catch {
    NSLog("An error happened while starting AEAudioController.")
}

let receiver = MyAudioReceiver();
audioController?.addInputReceiver(receiver)

class MyAudioReceiver : NSObject, AEAudioReceiver {
    var receiverCallback: AEAudioReceiverCallback! {
        // what do I do here?
    }
}
```

Now I'm getting an error in the `receiverCallback` property. Am I on the right track here or is my approach completely wrong?

I can't figure out how to do the exact same thing in Swift. How would I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What warnings/errors have you encountered that would lead you to believe that you can't accomplish this yourself?

Comment: @VatsalManot see the example code I added...

Comment: I'm trying to write this code into swift now. did you solved this?

Comment: I kind of moved on from the project, so I can't really tell you... ;)

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, functions and blocks are treated almost equally, with the unified notion of [closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html). I suggest you read up (along with the rest of the documentation) in order to understand closure syntax and semantics.

Comment: Could you tell me whether I'm going in the right direction? Or is what I'm trying completely off?

Comment: Just return a closure in `receiverCallback` (of type `AEAudioReceiverCallback`)

Answer (score 0):

here is a example from my working taae swift project

```
var receiverCallback: AEAudioReceiverCallback! {
    return  { (receiver:AnyObject?, audioController:AEAudioController?, source:UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, time:UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>, frames:UInt32, audio:UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>) -> Void in
        //do some thing with audio data here
    }
}
```

Comment: This compiles ok, but it crashes for me using TAAE 1.5.7

Comment: Never mind I got it to work eventually. The crash was caused by something else.